# Displaying user details after logging in

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring security for my web application, and I would like to display some of the logged in users' details. In my code, I am trying to use @Autowired on the user itself after logging in and use it as a model to display some of its fields on the frontend side:

```
  @Autowired
  public AttractionController(XyService xyService, 
  ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
   this.xyService= xyService;
   this.applicationUser = applicationUser;
 }

  @GetMapping("/")
  String main(Model model, @ModelAttribute 
  Attraction xy) {

   model.addAttribute("xy", xyService.findAll());
   model.addAttribute("user", applicationUser);
   return "main";
```

I think the problem is not only with the implementation, but also with the approach itself.

How should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of security are you using : basic auth, oauth1, oauth2, etc ?

Comment: Thanks for your question! I am using basic auth.

Comment: What is not working with your code? Any error message? Show your code of `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Do you need just a user information managed by spring or do you need an extensive user information : username, lastname, address, birthday, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ApplicationUser` is some kind of data class which holds user information, it is totally pointless to autowire it, since it is more like not controlled by Spring.

In order to get the currently authenticated user, you can simply use `SecurityContextHolder`. It can be instantiated in the following way:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

// check if there is somebody authenticated
if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
    String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
    // do something the the username, maybe get more information from a database
}
```